# Intermittent bug in comment @replies on Google chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comment-replies

I have come across an intermittent bug when replying to user comments with the @replies feature using Google chrome.

Normally when replying to a comment, I can type '@' and the first letter or two of the user name I want to reply to, and am presented with the complete name (auto-completion), and pressing tab the user name is filled in.

But, I would say probably about 10% of the time, this feature does not work. I type the '@' and a few letters of the user name, but there is no auto-completion, so I type the entire name and then the comment. But when I submit the comment, the @username is not present in the comment. Every time this occurs (I have no idea how to consistently reproduce it), I try to see if there is something specific about the user name, but have found no patterns (special chars, spaces, dots, commas, etc).

This happened yesterday, but I didnt have time to report it then. The next time this happens, I will update this question/bug with the details so as to help debug the problem.

I have read the faq and this [meta SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/184933), so I feel that Im familiar with the feature and using it correctly.

**Edit**: One more piece of info: Ive seen this on both windows XP and Vista.

Comment: Weird; I use Google Chrome also and leave tons of comments, but I've never seen this behavior. Do you have any user scripts installed that customize the behavior of one or more of the Stack Exchange sites? I remember [someone learned just recently that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133214/prevent-default-break-line-in-a-comment) a text formatting extension was responsible for adding inappropriate line breaks to his comments.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, I dont have anything special installed. (it worked great this time! :)

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is precisely what happens when you @mention the post owner, as Matt said in his answer (which he deleted after you said this isn't the reason). In particular, this part:

> But when I submit the comment, the @username is not present in the comment.

means that the @name is removed *on the server*, so this is independent of the browser you're using.

Unless you can give a concrete example, I'll have to assume that you were indeed trying to @mention the post owner.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. I'll see if I can reproduce it again and look for this. That may indeed by the case when I comment on an answer, then the answer owner replies, then I try to reply back and I didnt realize it.